# Search over all fields with highlighting

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I recently working with Elasticsearch 2 and would like to request a query over all text fields.

```
GET myindex/mydata/_search
```

```js
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Raketenfahrrad"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": [ { "*": {} } ]
  }
}
```

The query returns the expected results but without any highlighting. I experienced that I get highlighting when I narrow the search `fields` manually:

```js
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Raketenfahrrad",
      "fields": ["MainTitle","SubTitle","Author","Content"]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": [ { "*": {} } ]
  }
}
```

But that doesn't fit my requirement "Search over all" and will fail when the next new property is added to `mydata` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From *ES 2.0*, highlighting will be performed **only** on queried fields, you have to set `require_field_match` option to `false`. [Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_search_changes.html#_only_highlight_queried_fields) is the link to the change

Try this

```
{
  "query": {
    "simple_query_string": {
      "query": "Raketenfahrrad"
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    },
    "require_field_match" : false
  }
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work on latest Elasticsearch (Version 2.1.0, Lucene 5.3.1)! Could it be a bug?

Comment: I ran the query on 1.7, sorry about that, please have a look at my updated answer It is working on 2.0, does this help?

Comment: Hey, even shorter: `"highlight": { "fields": { "*": {"require_field_match" : false} } }`

Comment: In elasticsearch >= 5.6, `"require_field_match" : false` is not required. with 
`"highlight": {"fields": {"*": {}}}` it will work.